# Emulador android studio en AMD FX

Tags: android, android-studio

¿Se puede ejecutar el emulador de Android Studio en procesadores AMD FX?

Al principio me daba errores del tipo:

> Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
>   Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM)

Investigando me he dado cuenta que HAXM es una tecnología de Intel, en AMD su equivalente es AMD-V, pero mirando por internet he visto este hilo: [Intel's HAXM equivalent for AMD on Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263360/intels-haxm-equivalent-for-amd-on-windows-os) en el que dice que **solo es soportado en linux**.

También he probado a cambiar el emulador de X86 a ARMEABI:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera ya no genera errores y me lanza el emulador, pero no termina de ejecutar:

[image: Emulador con ARMEABI]

He dejado más de media hora y no ejecuta, se queda como la imagen anterior.

De momento voy ejecutando las aplicaciones desde mi móvil físico, ¿Qué me recomiendan?

Comment: Dependiendo de las especificaciones de tu pc, te recomiendo darle 2gb de almacenamiento, 1gb de ram y 256mb de heap.

Comment: las imagenes arm, te funcionarán pero 10 veces mas lentas, yo sufro lo mismo, y ya me estoy plateando en pillarme un i3 de la 6 generación para poder tirar de emulador.

Comment: No es por recursos del PC, tengo 12 GB de RAM y le suelo asignar 2GB de RAM, aún así tarda demasiado.

Comment: Listo, ya instalé el plugin en Android Studio y comprobé que funciona al inicarlo. La pregunta es, ¿cómo se hace para vicular el emulador de Genymotion con mi proyecto existente, para que ahora corra con este nuevo emulador y no con el que trae el IDE?
Mil gracias por la colaboración

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno pues he encontrado una solución: [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/thank-you-freemium/), supongo que la mayoría ya lo conocéis. Para los que no, es un emulador que nos permite configurar móviles reales de mercado, samsung, htc, sony...etc.

El caso es que nos sirve para solucionar el problema:

### Descarga e instalación de Genymotion

1 - Id a la página [www.Genymotion.com](https://www.genymotion.com/thank-you-freemium/) y descargar el programa e instala, existe una versión gratuita, supongo que estará limitada a uso no comercial.

2 - Cuando termine la instalación poner vuestro usuario y contraseña que habéis rellenado en su página web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3 - Ahora pulsar en add y elegir un emulador vereis que se descarga y se instala.

### Configuración de Android Studio

Para este apartado me he basado en un vídeo en inglés: [instalación plugin genymotion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byMla9XKk2c)

1 - En android studio vamos a File / Settings / Plugins / Browse repositories... Buscamos Genymotion e instalamos, nos pedirá reinstalar el IDE.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si todo ha ido bien os aparecerá la siguiente ventana:
[image: Imagen capturada del vídeo de youtube]

En mi caso no ha sido así, desconozco el motivo, pero para poder usar el emulador solo tenemos que abrir el programa Genymotion y ejecutar el emulador que creamos antes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo el emulador funcionando ejecutamos nuestro proyecto en Android Studio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen anterior, nos reconoce el dispositivo como si estuviera conectado al pc.

Comment: Regularmente uso dispositivos físicos para pruebas, no había usado Genymotion, me parece un muy buen tutorial, gracias por la aportación!